# Why do not have an intercept in lmer model (fixed effects) and how to interpret the result?

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, mixed-models

I do not understand why I do not have an intercept in output of my mixed effect model, I do not know how to interpret the result (fixed and random effects).
variable preste present the loss in rolling surface, pente mean slope, classeFunc is the functional class of the road and idp_troncon_tembec mean section identifier.

```
Fixed effects:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value
pente               -0.9215     0.2199  -4.191
agelog:classeFunc1  -6.2900     1.2868  -4.888
agelog:classeFunc2  -8.9555     1.1762  -7.614
agelog:classeFunc3 -11.7433     1.0861 -10.812


Random effects:
 Groups             Name   Variance Std.Dev.
 idp_troncon_tembec agelog 39.00    6.245   
 Residual                  81.68    9.038   
Number of obs: 192, groups:  idp_troncon_tembec, 111


Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            pente  agl:F1 agl:F2
aglg:clssF1 -0.219              
aglg:clssF2 -0.264  0.058       
aglg:clssF3 -0.297  0.065  0.078
```

Answer (score 2):

For intercept, `summary()` is what you need. For interpreting the result, note you entered a main effect for `pente` and interaction effects for the other variables. This means you can only interpret that much. You'll normally need an ancillary function to calculate statistical significance with `lme4` models. These functions are available in the packages `afex` or `lmerTest`. For instance, you could do:

```
install.packages('afex')
library(afex)

# Fill in your model
model = afex::lmer(DV ~ pente +  +  + , data)

anova(model)  # p-values (significance) calculated with Satterthwaite approximation
summary(model)  # details including intercept
```

Comment: Thanks Pablo for the answer it helped me. I forgot to note my model : lmer(preste ~ agelog:classeFunc + pente + (agelog + 0 | idp_troncon_tembec) - 1,offset = presteMax,data = BD). I used the packages lmerTest  :anova(model): according to the result below, can be said that interaction has more effect than pente?
` Pr(>F) pente 5.51e-05 ***
and  Pr(>F)agelog:classeFunc   < 2.2e-16 ***`

Comment: You're welcome! Very complicated issue. To compare the eff size of 'pente' with the interaction, you'd at least need: (1) to be certain, theory-wise, that you don't need the missing main effects for 'classeFunc', as well as the interaction of 'pente' with the other two vars, (2) to refer to an effect size such as 'F', rather than 'p' (formal issue). For the first condition, if in doubt, include all possible effects. Refs: (1) Andy Field's R or SPSS stats books ('Discovering statistics using...'), (2) Kam and Franzese (2007) http://www-personal.umich.edu/~franzese/FranzeseKam.Interactions.pdf

Comment: @rihab; you do not have an intercept as you remove it from your model with `-1`